# Xcode unexpected behaviour

Tags: xcode

When ever I am trying to create a New Swift Class, Its shows an unexpected view, Due to this unable to create new class.

**This is the issue, that I am Facing-**

[image]

Comment: Try to force quit Xcode and reopen it

Comment: open xcode preferences and add account

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: Restart your system after quiting your all active programs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear bug in Xcode (I can reproduce on my Xcode 7).

I suppose the problem is the combination of Xcode 7 and Mac OS Sierra (MacOS 10.12).

You can report it to Apple but Apple has already fixed the problem in Xcode 8, therefore they will only tell you to upgrade.

Upgrade to the latest version (currently Xcode 8).

Comment: But what happen of Xcode 7.3.1 ??? Almost my project in xcode 7 and Its seem like unable to update to Xcode 8 at this time.

Comment: @iDeveloper You can always upgrade. There is some little work needed but not much for Obj-C projects. Also, this is just a cosmetic problem, it doesn't affect functionality at all.

Comment: I am reading daily lots of questions at SO  about errors due to upgrade xcode 7 to xcode 8. So that I am feeling little bit  horrible.

Comment: @iDeveloper, there are tons of reports about troubles using Xcode 7 on macOS Sierra in the [Apple's dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/welcome). Which do you prefer, struggling with bugs which Apple might not fix, or doing some little work which many developers have already done.